# Angular 6 find and delete object

Tags: angular, typescript

How can an object in a list of objects be removed using an id number? Using Angular 6, written using TypeScript.

**EntityService.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Entity } from '../../models/entity';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EntityService {

  entities: Entity[] = [
    {
      id: 1, 
      name: 'Entity 1'
    },
    {
      id: 2, 
      name: 'Entity 2'
    },
    {
      id: 3, 
      name: 'Entity 3'
    }
  ];

  constructor() { }

  deleteEntity(id: number) {
    // ???
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter` to keep all items except the one that you want to delete:

```
deleteEntity(id: number) {
  this.entities = this.entities.filter(entity => entity.id !== id);
}
```

Comment: Even though this is correct, performance wise it will be slow

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to find and delete,there's a new method to do this in ES6/2015 using findIndex and array spread operator:

```
deleteEntity(id: number) {
    const index = Entities.findIndex(obj => obj.id === id);
    const newData = [
        ...Entities.slice(0, index)
    ];
}
```

**ADVANTAGE OVER ABOVE ANSWER:**

findIndex won't probably iterate over the whole list

```js
let Entities = [
    {
      id: 1, 
      name: 'Entity 1'
    },
    {
      id: 2, 
      name: 'Entity 2'
    },
    {
      id: 3, 
      name: 'Entity 3'
    }
  ];

let entityId = 3;
const index = Entities.findIndex(obj => obj.id === entityId);
const newData = [
    ...Entities.slice(0, index)
];

console.log(newData);
```